# Can we programmatically determine if Google Maps API authentication failed

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We have a site that loads the Google Maps API using a client id.

If the user comes to our site through a proxy that alters the domain, they may get an error "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The site is not authorized to use the Google Maps client ID provided..." because the domain authentication fails.

Is there a way for us to test the authentication prior to trying to load the maps api?  Can we call the authentication service ourselves, etc.?

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to check the current domain against the list of authorized domains?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way via the Google Maps API to programmatically tell if your client app is authenticated ***after*** you've already made an attempt to load the Maps API...

However, if you define this global function in your application, it will be called  upon an authentication failure.

```
function gm_authFailure() { /* Code */ };
```

Reference to documentation: 
[Listening for authentication errors](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors)

Perhaps you can use this to set a flag which you can then check programmatically at any time from that point onwards?

For example:

```
var failedAuthentication = false;
function gm_authFailure() { failedAuthentication = true };
```

Although I would be careful with the logic here, as it is basically assuming that authentication was successful.

Also, best to wrap this up in a module or something else so that your flag isn't in the global namespace.

See this excellent reference on Javascript patterns to better understand the Module Pattern:
[Javascript Patterns: The Module Pattern by Addy Osmani](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)